# value of element cant be set

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Within a function an HTML input element gets created. After calling the function the element is displayed on the position, I can type in it but I can not access it by my script.

After researching I added a check if the element does exist, if it does I still cant change its value in the script... 
I can change the value in the console with document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow").value = 'access me'

```
<div id = "searchResults"></div>

document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = '<input id="txtSearchBelow"class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..">'+'<br>';
var inputBelow = document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow");
console.log(inputBelow);
console.log('until here it seems fine.');
var element = document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow");
 //If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){
    alert('Element exists!');
// this here doesnt work. why not?
    document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow").value = 'eyyy please access me'; 
} else{
    alert('Element does not exist!');
}
```

How can it be that I can change the value by console but not in the script?

edit:

it works with an delay ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Most likely because it doesn't exist... Try adding `console.log(element)` instead of your alert. Then you will see what the element is exactly.

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/emrhdob2/

Comment: i have edited the post. now it has the function which does (not) work as explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it is because of the rendering time for it to create the element takes longer than the logic that follows it.

Meaning your var element = document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow"); is executing before the element is known to the browser.

Put in a delay timer before calling the document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow")

Comment: JS is synchronous, so the line that updates the innerHTML on an element will be completed before attempts to access the new element by ID is made. From OP's code there will be no race condition: the issue might be lying somewhere else.

Comment: I just ran your code and it appears to work just fine

Comment: i edited the question, now it has my actual code, which does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

It works quite right, I don't get your complains...

```js
document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = '<input id="txtSearchBelow"class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..">'+'<br>';
var inputBelow = document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow");
console.log(inputBelow);
console.log('until here it seems fine.');
var element = document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow");
// If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
    console.log('Element exists!');
    // This line works for me...!
    document.getElementById("txtSearchBelow").value = 'eyyy please access me'; 
} else {
    console.log('Element does not exist!');
}
```

```html
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

Comment: I agree with you. I ran it as well. No problem that I see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a browser problem? Computer system and loading delay is possible.
I can run it